# How can I get all the values ​of the inputs and put them in the right place in my object (localStorage)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I get all the values ​​of the inputs and put them in the right place in my object (localStorage) without having to retrieve them one by one as in the code below?

This is my function for update informations:

```
updateContact() {


    if (this.onSubmit()) {

      this.eleveService.apiUpdateEleve(this.token, this.registerForm.get("firstName").value, this.registerForm.get("lastName").value
      ).subscribe((data: any) => {

        // récupération des informations du formulaire
        this.student['contact']['us_firstname'] = this.registerForm.get("firstName").value;
        this.student['contact']['us_lastname'] = this.registerForm.get("lastName").value;
        //  this.language = this.student['us_lang'] 
        this.student['us_lang'] = this.lang
        this.translate.use(this.student['us_lang']);

        // MAJ de l'objet
        localStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(this.student));
        console.log('maj', this.student)
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/e-tabs/explorer');

      })

    }

  }
```

This is my Object :

```
OBJECT :

contact:
country: {id: "BE", name: "Belgique"}
login: "last@last.be"
newsletter: "1"
prest_feedback: "1"
us_address: "Rue des polders 13"
us_city: "Uccle"
us_email: "test@test.be"
us_firstname: "Munir"
us_gsm: "0485001128"
us_id: "5c9b35d8b4dd1"
us_lang: "fr"
us_lastname: "Nahman"
us_zip: "1180"
[Object][1]
[Front-end of the page][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmxSZ.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oknZd.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are all key-value pairs, The shortest way to do it will be to stringify and store the entire object inside your localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem('contactObject', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
```

And when you want to retrieve the object from localStorage, you can simply retrieve and parse it back as an object.

```
const retreivedContactObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contactObject'));
console.log(retreivedContactObject);
```

---

EDIT: I recommend you to set your `registerForm` FormControl names to be the same as your `student` object.

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
  .
  .

student = {
  contact: {
    custName: undefined,
    custAddress: undefined,
    custTown: undefined,
    .
    .
  }
};

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

registerForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  custName: [null, Validators.required],
  custAddress: [null, Validators.required],
  custTown: [null, Validators.required],
    .
    .
},
```

Once you have set your formControls to have the same name as your student object,

you can simply update your `student` this way:

```
this.student.contact = {...this.registerForm.value};
//console.log(this.student);
```

Comment: My question is : When i change the inputs , how can i update all the object with the new information given in the form..not how to store my object in the LocalStorage...it is all ready done and I managed to save the data but that field by field but it makes the code too long..

Comment: Alright, I was confused by your very first sentence on the question.

Comment: I am still confused. Are you trying to update your localStorage? The `this.student` object? Or the values on your `registerForm`?

Comment: i am trying to update my this.student object with the values of my registerForm..

Comment: Do your FormControls of `registerForm` and the properties in `student` object have the same name?

Comment: `console.log(this.registerForm.value)`. And show me the printed values.

Comment: i don't know how to put an image here..

address: ""
custAddress: ""
custName: ""
custTown: ""
custZipCode: ""
email: ""
firstName: "Munir"
lastName: "Nahman"
phone: ""
town: ""
tva: ""
zipCode: ""

Comment: Ok, why not we start with giving both the object and your formControlNames the same property names? If you can do that, it will be very easy to update the values accordingly

Comment: can you give me an example for how to do it for one field plz ?

Comment: Ok. Give me a moment. You are using reactive forms, right?

Comment: Yes, i use reactive forms.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my code. You can see if it makes sense and suits your project's requirements?

Comment: Ok, i will try it. Thank you very much

Comment: ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'contact.us_firstname'

Answer (score 0):

```js
var student = {
   contact: {
    name: "hello",
    class: "hello",
    age: "hello",
    gender: "hello",
    number: "hello",
    username: "hello",
    email: "hello",
    home: "hello",
    mobile: "hello"
   }
};

for ( var property in student.contact ) {
  console.log(property , student.contact[property])
}
```

This will allow you to get property name and its value. then you can do something like this. if i understand properly

```
for ( var property in this.student.contact ) { 
    this.student['contact'][property] = this.registerForm.get(property).value;
}
```